# How can I add a .npmrc file?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I installed node on my Mac OS Sierra. I use Windows at my work so there I have a .npmrc file in the node folder but I don't seem to find that in mac.
The problem is I want to add a registry of the format

```
    "scope=rohit-project@rohit-aquila:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
    //registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=some-token"
```

How do I add it so that I can install the dependencies and modules for my project by running npm install on MAC OS Sierra.

I created a .npmrc file simply and added the above code...and therefater running npm install I get the following error

```
    rohitsrivastava$ npm install
    npm ERR! Darwin 16.4.0
    npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
    npm ERR! node v7.7.3
    npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
    npm ERR! code E404

    npm ERR! 404 Not found : @rohit-project/notes
    npm ERR! 404 
    npm ERR! 404  '@rohit-project/notes' is not in the npm registry.
    npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
    npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of '@rohit-project/mega'
    npm ERR! 404 
    npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
    npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Comment: .npmrc is created when you `npm login` but you should be able to simply create a file at `Users/rohit/.npmrc` (username dependant) with that content. I hope that's not your real authToken..

Comment: call me paranoid, but I see no reason for you asking me to click a link to a google doc when you could add any extra information to your post so others could possibly assist as well. (http://gizmodo.com/beware-of-this-dangerously-convincing-google-docs-phish-1546278702)

Comment: @lecstor Sorry for that.Just started using Stack Overflow yesterday.

Comment: np. are the line endings correct? I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. I don't imagine there would be any other significant differences in this file between Windows and Mac.

Comment: Is that your access token? Might want to go to https://www.npmjs.com/settings/binaryspike/tokens/ and delete it now it's public.

Comment: pro tip, if you already have an `.npmrc` file, you can type `npm config edit` from the command line to open you npmrc file

Answer (score 188, accepted):

There are a few different points here:

1. Where is the `.npmrc` file created.
2. How can you download private packages

Running `npm config ls -l` will show you all the implicit settings for npm, including what it thinks is the right place to put the `.npmrc` (the field `userconfig`), as this is environment/operating system dependant. But if you have never logged in (using `npm login`) it will be empty. Simply log in to create it.

To just output the path prop, issue `npm config get userconfig`.

Another thing is #2 - downloading private packages. You can actually do that by putting a `.npmrc` file in the NPM package's root. It will then be used by NPM when authenticating. It also supports variable interpolation from your shell so you could do stuff like this:

```
; Get the auth token to use for fetching private packages from our private scope
; see http://blog.npmjs.org/post/118393368555/deploying-with-npm-private-modules
; and also https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

**Pointers**

- http://blog.npmjs.org/post/118393368555/deploying-with-npm-private-modules
- https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc

Comment: So `npm` knows how to read `.npmrc` lines like `//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}`?  That looks different from the other lines, which are `key = value` format.  I'm just curious why that line is different.  I see this blog post that shows it, but it doesn't explain how it works: https://blog.npmjs.org/post/118393368555/deploying-with-npm-private-modules

Comment: you can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53281483/2839274

Comment: Heads up, I had to upgrade my version of NPM as the version I was on didn't allow for use of `alias`s

Comment: @Jacksonkr Not sure why this is relevant. We do not use an `alias` commands here, AFAIK. How does your "alias" issue affect anything in this answer?

Comment: @oligofren My comment is not meant as a critique, more of a "if you find yourself using this answer as a potential solution and get stuck with an issue regarding aliases such as I did, here's a reminder check your NPM install for a potential update"

Comment: OK ... I did not take it as a critique, but I still not see that it relates to this question or this answer in general. Having an alias or not is not going to make a shred of difference. It is like saying "If you read this answer and have troubles with your Mercedes, try shifting changing your brakes" :) I am sure posting a separate Q&A in a separate answer will give more relevant results for anyone searching for alias issues :)

Answer (score 25):

In MacOS Catalina 10.15.5 the `.npmrc` file path can be found at

```
/Users/<user-name>/.npmrc
```

Open in it in (for first time users, create a new file) any editor and copy-paste your token. Save it.

You are ready to go.

**Note:**
As mentioned by @oligofren, the command `npm config ls -l` will npm configurations. You will get the .npmrc file from config parameter `userconfig`

Comment: Upvoting this one because I'm too dumb to find the correct config property in the whole config on my own.

Comment: @Carrm Both @sunil and the accepted answer literally gives you this oneliner: `npm config get userconfig`. No need to find anything.

Comment: @oligofren Thanks but you updated your post with this information 5 days after I wrote my comment. At the time of the comment, only sunil posted the property to look for. Yours only got me a whole bunch of config parameters. So yeah, there was a need to go through the whole list of properties to find the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is because of you having some local or private packages. 
For accessing those packages you have to create `.npmrc` file for this issue. Just refer the following link for your solution. https://nodesource.com/blog/configuring-your-npmrc-for-an-optimal-node-js-environment

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using VSTS run `vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc` to generate new .npmrc file with the auth token

Comment: It only works in Windows and non-bash environments

Comment: As of 2017 VSTS is deprecated. " The Azure CLI with the Azure DevOps extension has replaced the VSTS CLI. The VSTS CLI has been deprecated and will no longer be receiving new features. We recommend that users of the VSTS CLI switch to the Azure CLI and add the Azure DevOps extension."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/vsts/overview?view=vsts-cli-latest

Answer (score 1):

In my case, updating my npm version helped me. So just to be sure, make sure your npm is up to date.

`npm install -g npm@latest`

Answer (score 1):

In case if you want to have .npmrc file at project level

1. In the root directory of your project, create .npmrc file.
2. In the .npmrc file, add key=value
3. Save and close the file.