# what do lines starting with double-slash '//' mean in a .npmrc?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'd naively assumed that .npmrc lines with double slash ('//') indicate a comment, but that's clearly not the case, because when I delete them, I'm unable to publish to my local registry.

Example:

```
registry=https://npm.myregistry.io/
//email=me@mydomain.com
//npm.myregistry.io/:_authToken="Pgwb34F123EQdHqE7OoZA=="
```

If I remove the above // lines, publish results in

```
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth auth required for publishing
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
```

I can't find any reference to this syntax in npmrc documentation or the ini module parser documentation.  I'm assuming it has something to do with synthesized properties?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`//` has no special meaning in `.npmrc` or any other `.ini` file.

The ini syntax is `key = value`. So in this case the key is `//npm.myregistry.io/:_authToken`.

This is a [Protocol-relative URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#prurl), meaning an URL that will take the protocol automatically from the current page (you can actually type `//google.com` in the browser, and it should take you to `https://google.com`)

Note that this may not necessarily be the URL used by npm for authentication. It's just a format chosen by the developers to hold the `authToken` (or other values) in the same string with the registry URL.

Comment: Good explanation @mihai. However, why is the key name `//npm.myregistry.io/:_authToken` instead of `npm.myregistry.io/:_authToken` (i.e. without `//` prefix)? Why use a Protocol-relative URL for a key name in this context of a _.npmrc_? Seems to me that a Protocol-relative URL would make more sense as a value and not a key.

Comment: For me, when typing `//google.com` in the browser _(FF, Safari, and Chrome)_ it resolves to `file:////google.com`

Comment: @RobC it probably has to do with the internal logic of npm. What's stored in the `.npmrc` is not necessarily the URL used for authentification, it's just a way to hold the `authToken` in a format that also contains the registry URL. [Here](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/58ece8973f43c77b1f4f44ded0f49556ad30eb57/lib/config/get-credentials-by-uri.js#L31) is where the token is read in the source code.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. In the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc#comments) for _.npmrc_ it says files are parsed by [npm/ini](https://github.com/npm/ini). However I couldn't find any obvious indication of how `//` is parsed in the [source](https://github.com/npm/ini/blob/master/ini.js) code and it's many RegExp's.

Comment: you're right, there doesn't seem to be any special logic, because they don't mean anything for the ini format. The key in this case has a meaning only internally for npm

Comment: Ok, protocol-relative URLs are plausible, except that other entries also have a // that don't seem to be URIs, i.e. in my example above, there's //email=

Comment: The answer of "the key in this case has a meaning only internally for npm" is, well, tautologically unhelpful, in that my question is that "given that these keys/values are undocumented as part of "npmrc(5)" or "ini", what does this syntax mean to npm?"

Comment: @JollyRoger what’s stopping you from raising a github issue asking them to document the entries

Comment: Raising a github issue to document the format is an orthogonal concern to just understanding the format.  I'm accepting your answer because it's factually correct.  I will say that the implementation decision to use protocol-relative URLs to encode ini key-value pairs is certainly... how to say... not what I would have chosen.

Comment: @JollyRoger do you have a link to the issue you raised? A quick search didn't turn up any results.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [nmpjs docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/npmrc#comments), the .npmrc interprets a line as a comment when it begins with ; or #

The "//registry.npmjs.org/:" is referenced [in the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/npmrc#auth-related-configuration) as an "URI fragment", which should be used in order to scope authentication related configuration like "_authToken".