# deploying private npm package in Azure

Tags: angular, git, azure, npm

I have git integration for my Angular web site. I check code in Git, code get deployed to Azure. Everything works great! Till I want to pull a private npm package. Finally realized this may need AzureDevOps but not the VS Code azure integration, which I was using all this time.

I updated  the .npmrc file as follows

```
registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MyCompanyName/_packaging/packageName/npm/registry/
always-auth=true

user .npmrc as follows

//registry.npmjs.org/:username=myname
//registry.npmjs.org/:email=my@hotmail.com
//registry.npmjs.org/:always-auth=true
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=6544990b-a2f2-472b-8daa-23f8b0977330
```

-- EDITED --
went to Azure Dev ops route
[image: Ass upstream]
But I don't see any where were I can add a private npm login information. 
Does AzureDevOps support private npm package? I have a different login pwd for npm then my AzureDevOps userId.

Please help. How I can pull my private npm packages?

Answer (score 0):

Check the syntax of the `npmrc`.

In all the [examples](http://getpiggybank.com/blog/npm-private-modules-with-heroku/) I [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43066714/6309) as in this [blog post](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/118393368555/deploying-with-npm-private-modules), those lines stats with '`//`'

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=...
```

However, as the OP noticed, this requires *not* the [VSCode Azure extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/azure/extensions), but rather the [Azure DevOps services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/devops/), with extensions like [VSCode Azure Repos](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-repos-vscode).

An Azure Devops setting uses an [upstream source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops), which requires an upstream [view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/views?view=azure-devops), illustrated here

But... referencing [private upstreams was in the work](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:jte7L8TRnPAJ:https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-azure-devops-formerly-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/33510571-vsts-private-upstream-package-sources%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=fr&client=firefox-b-d). It is [unclear if it is available](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/320569/unable-to-add-upstream-source-to-vsts-grayed-out.html).

Comment: Thanks VonC. Actually in code it is double slashes "//". I will update the question. I wasted many hours, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @NetMagician OK, not sure then. Maybe npmjs.com has not been established as an upstream on Azure side? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops). Or a scope issue (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/scopes?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows)

Comment: @NetMagician I have edited the answer with what I have found... no definitive answer yet.