# Understanding .npmrc

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, macos, npm

I am new to the npm. I have the npm documentation ([here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc) and [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#npmrc-files)) to help me understand how to add .npmrc file to my project, however I am unable to grasp the concept of logging in ( as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877722/node-npmrc-file)) just to make .npmrc file. FWIW I can simply create a new file by right clicking on the project and add a new file. I dont understand what that login is for? What purpose does it serve? It would be great if someone can really explain this concept in detail. And also explain how can I create .npmrc and force my project to read its settings from .npmrc? Thank you.

Comment: If the file is there npm will use it. Logging in is for your npm account, ie to publish, when you don't want to set it globally

Comment: Publish what and why? You may wanna give a bit more detail as the same thing was written in the docs.

Comment: Publish your package for others to install and use.

Comment: I don't want to publish my package to the outside world. I just want my project to be able to read the config from .npmrc. Does publish help anyway with Jenkins?

Comment: You don't have to publish. I'm explaining one reason for logging in via `.npmrc`

Comment: Oh ok. And what credentials does it need? Personal vs corporate?

Comment: That depends on your package, who owns it, etc.. Also, you don't have to enter any credentials if you won't be doing things which require them.

Comment: .npmrc is the configurable file for npm as .gitconfig for git, useful when creating , publishing new packages to npm, setting registry ,

Comment: I tried npm login. I kept hitting enter and I kept getting a field to enter a username. So I guess you have to enter the creds. Once I added the creds it just didnt do anything. .npmrc file wasnt created.